# matplotlib, graph with points on the edges which correspond to points in the graph

Tags: python, matplotlib, wxpython

[image: 1]
Here is an example, i want to know if this is possible in matplotlib with wxpython

Basically there are coloured parts around the side of the graph which correspond to points on the graph, and when you click on either the blue or the red part it highlights the points on the graph that are related to it

If there is anyway of doing this are there any examples online, or if anyone has done anything similar could they please help to put me on the right track

I am wanting to use wxpthon and matplotlib to create this
Thanks in advance

Dave

Comment: have you had a look at this: http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2008/08/01/matplotlib-with-wxpython-guis/

Comment: Yes i have and neither of the examples help with what i want to do unfortunately

Comment: Is this some kind of recurrence plot?

Comment: would some variation of [this example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/scatter_hist.html) work?